# encrypted ext3 damaged; how to proceed?

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, fsck

My home partition on a Debian wheezy install is an encrypted LVM volume. It is ext3. Earlier today, I had a weird message in a terminal window about an attempt to write to a file in my `/home` tree failing due to having a read only file system. I rebooted and ended up with an error message saying `/dev/sda1 is reported as clean. fsck.ext3`, which runs automatically and reports that there is no such device as `/dev/mapper/sda1_crypt` and reports exit code 8. I get dropped to a maintenance  shell and told there was an attempt to write a log to `/var/log/fsck/checkfs`.

That log reads:

```
[Timestamp]

fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/mapper/sda1_crypt: Super blocks need_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
/dev/mapper/sda1_crypt: Run journal anyway

/dev/mapper/sda1_crypt: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY
     (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck died with exit status 4
```

I ran

```
$ fsck -vnM /dev/mapper/sda1
```

A bunch of `illegal block #nnnn (mmmmmmmmm) in inode ppppppp IGNORED` messages blew past, followed by

```
too many blocks in Inode somenumberhere
```

Then running additional passes to resolve blocks claimed by more than one inode

It then output

```
Pass 1B: Rescanning for multiply claimed blocks
```

After a bit, I got a wall of

```
Illegal block number passed to ext2fs_test_block_bitmap somenumberhere for multiply claimed block map
```

These were followed by 2 Multiply claimed blocks in I node anothernumber: [lists of 5 and 8 block numbers]

Then I got a number of stanzas like

```
[ 3828.181915] ata1.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[ 3828.182462] ata1.01 BMDMA stat 0x64
[ 3828.183810] ata1.01 failed command: READ DMA EXT
[ 3828.185889] ata1.01 cmd 25/00:08:08:10:9c/00:00:29:00:00/f0 tag dma 4096 in
[ 3828.185891] res 51/40:00:09:10:9c/40:00:29:00:00/f0 Emask 0x9 (media error)
[ 3828.190071] ata1.01 status: { DRDY ERR }
[ 3828.192153] ata1.01 status: { UNC }
```

These were followed by

```
[ 3830.509338] end_request: I/O error, deb SDA, sector 698093577
[ 3830.509841] Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 87261184
Error reading block 87261184 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read) while reading I node and block bitmaps. Ignore error? no

fsck.ext3: Can't read an block bitmap while retrying to read bitmaps for /dev/mappersfa1_crypt

/dev/mapper/sda1_crypt: ******* WARNING: Filesystem still has errors *******

e2fsck: aborted

/dev/mapper/sda1_crypt: ******* WARNING: Filesystem still has errors *******
```

And the it aborted with a warning that the filesystem still had errors.

My questions are:

1. Is my data toasted? (My rigorous backup policy hasn't been rigorously followed of late; I am being punished by the universe, I am sure.)
2. What can/ought I to do now?
3. Did I do the wrong thing already?
4. Will someone hold me until the shaking stops?

EDIT

I also asked on my local LUG mailing list. The advice I got there was to take an image of the drive with ddrescue and run fsck on a copy of that image. That seems sound and unlikely to make things worse. So, that is the present plan of attack, pending any better suggestions.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks for the markup, etc edits. A combination of being distraught and stuck with a phone for the moment doesn't excuse my being lazy.

Comment: I think ddrescue would be a good idea. You probably will have to reinstall Debian, but you still might be able to salvage documents, a list of the packages you had installed, etc.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like the hard disk itself is having problems. ("short read," etc.) If so, `dmesg | tail` will probably show some I/O errors.

Another way to check this is to run `badblocks -n` on the problem partition. Or better, on the entire disk. Whatever you test, it needs to be unmounted. This will take hours on a large modern disk. If there's anything on the partition(s) that do mount that you can't live without, copy it off onto removable media or a network volume first.

The suggestion to mirror the disk is also good. It's kind of a "lite" version of the `badblocks -n` check, because by forcing the disk to read in every sector, it can cause the disk to relocate problem blocks, as `badblocks -n` will. `badblocks -n` is more effective because dodgy sectors can be barely-readable, and only be shown to the disk as bad enough to move by attempting to write to them. Still, if the disk has enough life left in it to survive a rescue, the extra read pass won't be enough to finish it off.

I don't hold much hope that running `fsck` on the disk image will recover everything. You'll almost certainly lose sectors in this process, which means some files will be unreadable or corrupted beyond use. A JPEG will partially decode with corrupted data, for example, but a JPEG with the bottom ⅔ cropped off might not be useful to you.

> Is my data toasted?

Possibly, possibly not. The `badblocks -n` pass can sometimes fix the problem. If it does, you still need to replace the HDD, since a disk can only get into such a bad state by being nearly dead to start.

> Did I do the wrong thing already?

Other than forgetting the meaning of the word "rigorous," no. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have a current backup image from which to restore from.

I'd take a limited backup NOW of anything you wish to preserve and then check to see if the disk is still usable.  One trick I used to use was to use the RAW partition device and dd it to /dev/null.....with an appropriate option an area that could not be read would be identified.

Comment: Well, I can't backup anything because the filesystem problems prevent me from getting as far as decrypting the disk on boot. Rather than try to mount it manually, I think I will take an image of the while thing first. And no, I don't have a recent enough backup so as not to feel sick :-(

Comment: What about using the rescue disk?